# Prevent user from adding same values to the database

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert

I am developing an Attendance Monitoring System with register module. Every time I click the register button for the 2nd time, it inserts a new row, but it should prevent the user from doing so. I am using C# with MS Access

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: This can be handled in so many ways. You could disable the button immediately upon insert and re-enable it only when the context changes. You could insert through an SP (or function in case of Access) and check whether a record already exists.

Comment: Or just change the logic: store absentees instead of attendees. This will save some disk space too, unless your users are normally absent.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `duplication` of data:

> Use `Primary Key` Constraints.

This is the only way to hold any duplicate Primary Key value.(No more insertion happen again if value exists.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to retrieve a list of names from MS Access, then when the user tries to add a new value to MS Access, compare the value they have entered with the values stored in your list. If the new value matches an already existing value, don't execute the insert code.